# как сохранить сессию steam после перезапуска сервера

Tags: node.js

есть модули steam community, steam user. сколько бился, не могу понять, как сохранять сессию, чтобы после перезапуска сервера она работала.

Comment: Я, конечно, не владею Steam API, но... Сессия - это сессия. Если выключить и включить - сессия будет новая.